# Elegant way to combine two lists by a specific key-value in both

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iterator

I have two lists, `listA` and `listB`. Both contain instances of a class that has the function `get_values`, which returns another list of values.

So, `listA` contains

```
[<MyInstance1>, <MyInstance2>, <MyInstance3>]
```

While `libstB`

```
[<MyInstance4>, <MyInstance5>, <MyInstance6>]
```

I can get the values by:

```
print([x.get_values() for x in listA])
```

Output:

```
[
    ['dummy', 'dummy:red', 'dummy'],
    ['dummy', 'dummy:yellow', 'dummy'],
    ['dummy']
]
```

For `listB`

```
print([x.get_values() for x in listB])
```

Output:

```
[
    ['dummy2', 'dummy2', 'yellow', 'dummy2'],
    ['dummy2', 'dummy2', 'red', 'dummy2'],
    ['dummy2']
]
```

I want to get a list of tuples containing the pair of instances that have the same value, discarding the values labeled as `dummy` or `dummy2`.

The position of the values will be the same, so for `listA get_values()` I only care about the second element, while on `listB get_values()` I only care about the third element.

In this case, I would get:

```
[
    (<MyInstance1>, <MyInstance5>), # Because they both have "red"
    (<MyInstance2>, <MyInstance4>), # Because they both have "yellow"
    (<MyInstance3>, <MyInstance6>)  # Because they neither have any value
]
```

I'm trying to avoid a nested for, I'm looking for the most Pythonic and/or elegant way to handle this. I'm guessing something with itertools or lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Your last condition seems off to me because you have values of "dummy" in one list and "dummy2" in the other, but this should satisfy your other conditions:

```
class Blah:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals

    def get_values(self):
        return self.vals

lst1 = [Blah(['dummy', 'red', 'dummy']),
        Blah(['dummy', 'yellow', 'dummy']),
        Blah(['dummy'])]

lst2 = [Blah(['dummy2', 'dummy2', 'yellow', 'dummy2']),
        Blah(['dummy2', 'dummy2', 'red', 'dummy2']),
        Blah(['dummy2'])]

output = [(item1, item2) for item1 in lst1 for item2 in lst2
          if set(item1.get_values()).intersection(item2.get_values())]
```

Comment: So this *is* a nested for, but using array comprehension, right? One think that seems like I didn't express correctly, is that one element in listA has the value I'm looking for as part of the value, as `dummy:red`. Intersection should work if values are exactly the same, right?

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the error in my question: I don't care about dummy2 either.